# Wordpress: Latest post missing from category feed

Tags: php, wordpress

I have setup a custom field to pull a specified category ID to display using WP_Query on a page's side bar. It pulls the posts in the correct category, but skips the most recent one. Here is the snip of code:

```
<?php
    $catID = get_field ( 'category_id_posts' );
    $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat='. $catID .'&posts_per_page=5' );
    ?>
    <?php if($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
    <div id="recent-posts-2">       
        <h3 class="widget-title">Recent Posts</h3>
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Even when I simplify the WP_Query and remove the variable like this:

```
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=7&posts_per_page=5' );
```

It still skips over the latest post within that category.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to check if $catquery->have_posts() for example -

```
<?php if ( $catquery->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ( $catquery->have_posts() ) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
..
..
..
..
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif;
  wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting the first post, because you skip it.

Check this line:

```
<?php if($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
```

You check if your query has post, if yes, you will fetch the first one. However, you are not printing that one. Than you are calling ...

```
<?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
```

... again. This will give you the second post, and you skipped the first one.
Parse the first one directly or remove the first fetching.